# What is this aircraft from "Devil Girl From Mars" (1954)?

Tags: aircraft-identification

This view is cropped from the opening seconds of the film [*Devil Girl From Mars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Girl_from_Mars). Within the film narrative, this one was supposedly carrying passengers over the Scottish Highlands in the then-present-day, which turns out to be 1954.

[image: Aircraft seen very briefly in a 1954 film]

If you can help me with the type, I can find most of the other information I need by myself.  However, I would also be interested to know

- (a) whether there is anything to be discovered from the barely-visible markings, and
- (b) if it's possible to tell whether this shot represents a particular model of the type in question, and what that might say about the background of this specific machine (regardless of context in the film).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a [Vickers VC.1 Viking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_VC.1_Viking) in the livery of [British European Airways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_European_Airways) (BEA).

[image]

<sup>(By RuthAS (Own work) [CC BY 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0)], via Wikimedia Commons)</sup>

Comment: The particular type would be [610](https://yooniqimages.com/images/detail/216315916/Creative/vickers-type-610-viking-1b-g-aivh-vicinity), the type built for BEA, according to Wikipedia.